# Cleaning recipes after build in Yocto

Tags: build, embedded-linux, yocto

I know to reduce the disk space, we need to add INHERIT += "rm_work" in the local.conf, I added in local.conf, but it is still not deleting the files after building the recipe.

```
bitbake -e core-image-minimal | grep ^INHERIT
INHERIT=" multilib_global rm_work poky-sanity uninative package_rpm buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink debian devshell sstate license remove-libtool blacklist sanity"
INHERIT_BLACKLIST="blacklist"
INHERIT_DISTRO="debian devshell sstate license remove-libtool"
```

I verified by looking at log.task_order of a particular recipe, what I am missing here.

```
do_fetch (12251): log.do_fetch.12251
do_prepare_recipe_sysroot (12440): log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.12440
do_unpack (13072): log.do_unpack.13072
do_patch (14329): log.do_patch.14329
do_configure (15730): log.do_configure.15730
do_compile (4380): log.do_compile.4380
do_mkimage (10675): log.do_mkimage.10675
do_install (10749): log.do_install.10749
do_package (11298): log.do_package.11298
do_packagedata (6787): log.do_packagedata.6787
do_package_write_rpm (27291): log.do_package_write_rpm.27291
```

Comment: Do you have exceptions using `RM_WORK_EXCLUDE += "zbar"`? Otherwise it should work. Else try `cleansstate` for that recipe and re-try it!

Comment: No I don't have any EXCLUDE defined in local.conf

Comment: Looks strange. All of your recipes are not cleaned or just one?

Comment: All are not cleaned

Comment: Which yocto version and branch?

Comment: I am using Intel iotg bsp sumo branch

Comment: Share the URL for the meta layer.

Comment: https://github.com/intel/iotg-yocto-bsp-public/tree/e3900/master

Comment: Not sure. Try `bitbake -c listtasks <recipe name>`. If it doesn't show `do_rm_work` task, then inherit rm_work somehow overridden or removed. Intel layers are always complex!

Comment: Try sending email to maintainer or IRC should help in such cases!